# How to change the path when cloning the Taxonomy term view?

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases

I am trying to clone the default Taxonomy Term view to a new view.

I have a Block with the list of contents when I was clicking one of the content inside the Block, it goes to this path: taxonomy/term/%.

But I want to change the path to blog/%

I have changed the Path in the view's settings to (blog/%) from (taxonomy/term/%),But when I will click the content in the block goes to the same Taxonomy/term/% not to new wanted path.

How to change the taxonomy/term/% path to blog/% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the path that user's will see, you don't actually want to update the view path (which is not obvious), you need to change the path of the taxonomy vocabulary and its terms.  The [Pathauto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) makes this easy by creating a pattern for your blog taxonomy at: /admin/config/search/path/patterns (once pathauto is installed and working)